# GNU screen 4.2.1 in xterm: hardstatus in window title disappears

Tags: gnu-screen, xterm

The only 2 lines in my ~/.screenrc are:

1. termcapinfo xterm* 'hs:ts=\E]2;:fs=\007:ds=\E]2;screen\007'
2. hardstatus string "%h [screen %n%?: %t%?]"

In GNU screen version 4.0.3 that I used previously, it set the hardstatus to be in the window title to something like:

computer_name ~ [screen 0: bash]

However, after upgrading GNU screen to version 4.2.1, the "[screen 0: bash]" part of the hardstatus in the window title disappears after I hit enter in the terminal. The "computer_name ~" part stays there. However, the "[screen 0: bash]" reappears when switching windows (e.g. doing a "C-a n"), or creating a new window ("C-a c").

How do I get the hardstatus in the window title to stay put? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

That is my `screenrc` for many years, enjoy:

```
startup_message off
deflogin        off
nethack         on
vbell           off
msgminwait      0
msgwait         10
log             off
backtick        1 0 0 hostname
caption splitonly "%?%F%{= yk}%:%{= Kk}%? %n %t%="
hardstatus alwayslastline "%{= rY}  %1`  %{= bw}  %-w%{= Yk} %n %t %{-}%+w %=%{c} %l %{= bY} %0c "
```